# How to set up static sites with self hosted ghost on VPS

Tags: javascript, gatsby, ubuntu-20.04, self-hosting, ghost-blog

I just installed a ghost production environment on ubuntu 20.04 VPS with 1GB ram. I have also set up a dev environment locally on my mac where ill try out all my experiments.

My prod ghost installation is currently configured to the subdomain. ie.

```
blog.mydomain.com
```

I want to use ghost for managing most of my website, except for a few pages like the home page and my projects page, where I'd like to set up custom static sites with next.js or gatsby.

Is there any way to configure ghost to a subfolder within my root - and run

```
mycompany.com/blog
```

and use ssgs for the home and projects page.

If this isn't possible, Is there some other way to achieve this.

Thank you soo much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at [path prefixing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/)? Adding the following in your `gatsby-config.js` should change your (sub)domain to `/blog`:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

Be aware that adding a `pathPrefix` you will force you to tweak your build and serve commands by adding the `--prefix-paths` flag